# How to update all DEFINER from all VIEWs

Tags: mysql, sql

I removed previous user and created new user.

but all views have previous definer:

all sources have this `DEFINER` :

```
CREATE DEFINER = previous_user@`%` VIEW
```

How to update definer of all views?

Answer (score 0):

[ALTER VIEW](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-view.html)

Needs to be done per view however.

With creative use of CONCAT and [information_schema.VIEWS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/views-table.html) you can generate the SQL to change them all however.